# django replace whispace in url with plus sign

Tags: django, python-2.7

i have names in my models that are separated by whitespace. Example: **Don Joe** and it's k..i wanted it like this but in the urls it shows up like this  **https://example.com/details/Don Joe**  i want to replace that whitespace with a plus sign **+**.

This is part of my **urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<ps_name>.+)$', views.details, name='details'),
```

This is part of my **main.html**

```
    {% for ps in users %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="{% url 'main:details'  ps_name=ps.ps_name %}">{{ ps.ps_name }}</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

And this is part of my views.py

```
def details(request, ps_name):
    ps = Seotube.objects.filter(ps_name=ps_name)
    name = str(ps_name)

    return render(request, 'main/details.html', {'name': name,
                                                 'pornstars': ps})
```

I do want to keep the name normal with whitespace only in the url i want to have a plus sign instead of whitespace. Because i also call that name in in the **details.html**

```
{% if name %}
    <h1> {{ name }}</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably add a separate field to your model, e.g. `slug`, which can then be used to build the urls.

I would suggest using Django's built-in model field called [SlugField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) and then overriding your model's `save` method to populate the field's value whenever the instances of that model are updated:

```
# models.py

from django.utils.text import slugify


class YourModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(YourModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you really want to use `+` instead of `-` (which is what the `slugify` utility will replace all the spaces with), you can have your custom logic to update the value.

Comment: thank you for the help... do i create this function in the models.py file?

Comment: @Omega, I updated the answer to make it a bit clearer on where exactly should you put the snippet.